# Search for partial string in PHP array? Search value contains hashtag

Tags: php, arrays, regex

Example:

```
$array = array('alpha beta','beta gamma','delta phi', '#alpha phi', 'beta phi');
$searchword = 'alpha';
$results = array_filter($array, function($var) use ($searchword) { return preg_match("/\b$searchword\b/i", $var); });
print_r($results);

Array ( [0] => alpha beta [3] => #alpha phi )
```

I would like to find only the elements containing `#alpha`, not `alpha`.

The result I want is `Array ( [3] => #alpha phi )`.

However, this doesn't work:

```
$array = array('alpha beta','beta gamma','delta phi', '#alpha phi', 'beta phi');
$searchword = '#alpha';
$results = array_filter($array, function($var) use ($searchword) { return preg_match("/\b$searchword\b/i", $var); });
print_r($results);

Array ( )
```

I also tried `$searchword = preg_quote('#alpha');` but that doesn't work either. I'm not familiar enough with regex to figure this out-- there must be some regex rule I'm missing out on?

Note: I am not looking to find all the hashtag keywords in the array. I want to search for a specific hashtag keyword.

Credit: I used one of the answers from here:
[Search for PHP array element containing string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315536/search-for-php-array-element-containing-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the starting `\b`

```
preg_match("/$searchword\b/i", $var);
```

**or**

Use `\B`

```
preg_match("/\B$searchword\b/i", $var);
```

Why?

It's all about word boundaries `\b` matches between word char and a non-word char or vice-versa. Since the first character is `#` which is a non-word character and before that character there exists the start of the line boundary. `\B` is the suitable one for this, which matches between two non-word chars or two word chars. Here start of the line , `#` so there must exists `\B` in-between not `\b`.

Comment: $var is an array - just saying

Comment: @Feanne - you understand that this will match `*alpha`, `+alpha`, `%alpha` as well as the `#alpha` though - just thought I would mention that.  Oddly enough only my answer will match `#alpha` exactly and no other starting word.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix his search word is `#alpha`, then how it would match `*alpha`

Comment: sorry I was confusing \B don't see that used much, + its 330am here, my bad

Answer (score 2):

Drop the first `\b` [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) and use `$searchword = '#alpha';`
To search an array and get entries matching the pattern use [preg_grep function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php):

```
print_r(preg_grep("/".preg_quote($searchword, "/")."\b/i", $array));
```

> Array
>   (
>       [3] => #alpha phi
>   )

[Test at eval.in](https://eval.in/404591)

Comment: again the lack of the `^` anchor means this will also match `beta #alpha` as well as `b#alpha` etc.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Question was: ...Search value **contains**  hashtag

Answer (score 2):

Or you can also use `strpos` instead of `preg_match` as

```
$searchword = '#alpha';
$results = array_filter($array, function($var) use ($searchword) { return (strpos($var,$searchword)>-1); });
```

Comment: this will match `beta #alpha` as well as `b#alpha` etc.

Comment: Yep that might be the case

Answer (score 1):

Change your code

```
 $searchword = 'alpha';
```

To

```
$searchword = '^#alpha';
```

Starts with `^` `#` hashtag,

```
 preg_match('/^#alpha/', '#alphasomething');
```

Will match `#alpha`

https://regex101.com/r/rU1eA9/1

Doesn't match `alpha`

https://regex101.com/r/rU1eA9/2

Seeing as this is open to interpenetration

> I would like to find only the elements containing #alpha

Some answers may match a variety of things that "contain" `#alpha` such as `b#alphagama` or in some cases `gamma #alpha` etc.

I though I would mention the the leading `^` carrot in my RegX means begins with.  So in order for my answer to match the string must begin with a `#` hashtag followed by `alpha` literally.

So my answer may not be the best if you are just wanting the "contains" `#alpha` such as `gama#alpha`.  But if you want begins with `#alpha` I would recommend using it.

I feel it's important to make sure I high lighted these edge cases, and exactly what the leading `^` means in mine.