# Search specific value in array and return value

Tags: php, arrays

```
$meal_type= "Free Breakfast|Free Wireless";
if ($meal_type != '' && $meal_type !='None') {
    $meal = explode('|', $meal_type);

    $meal = array_search('Breakfast',$meal);

    $meal = $meal_type;
} else {
    $meal= 'No Breakfast';
}
echo $meal;
```

This is my code. here i want to search `Breakfast` in the array and return searched value, if not found return `No Breakfast`.

Here i was explode string to array with | symbol and returned array search Breakfast if exist return funded array value else echo No Breakfast value.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: i tried this but not working  `array_search('Breakfast',$meal_type);`

Comment: Update your question with your actual code and what you have tried. It will save everyone a lot of time. You may also have a small typo or spelling mistake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search for PHP array element containing string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315536/search-for-php-array-element-containing-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `foreach()` will do the job:-

```
<?php
$match_counter =0;
$array = Array
(
    0 => 'Free Breakfast',
    1 => 'Free Wireless Internet'
);
$search = 'Breakfast';

foreach($array as $arr){
    if(stripos($arr,$search) !==false){
        echo $arr.PHP_EOL;
        $match_counter++;
    }
}
if($match_counter ==0){
    echo 'No '.$search;
}
```

Output:-

https://3v4l.org/ogOEB (occurrence found)

https://3v4l.org/AOuTJ (occurrence not found)

https://3v4l.org/NTH1W (occurrence found more than one time)

Reference:- [stripos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)

Comment: thankx for reminding the (occurrence found more than one time)  cases

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 2):

```html
<?php
$array = array('Free Breakfast','Free Wireless Internet');

$string = 'Breakfast';
foreach ($array as $a) {


    if (stripos($a, $string) !== FALSE) {  
        echo  $string; 
        return true;
    }
}
echo "No" .$string;
return false;

?>
```

You can also use `stripos()` for case-insensitive.

case 1 : if array contains multiple same values

```html
<?php
$array = array('Free Breakfast','Free Wireless Internet' ,'breakfast time');

$string = 'Breakfast';
$flag=true;
foreach ($array as $key=> $a) {

    if (stripos($a, $string) !== FALSE) {  
        $flag = false;

        echo  $string." contain in key position ".$key.'<br>'; 
        //return true;
    }
}
if($flag)
{
echo "No" .$string;
}



?>
```

Comment: Your answer correct for current scenario, but it will not cover all occurrences, if presented more than one time inside the array:-https://3v4l.org/ND0IF

Comment: @AlivetoDie I added some code for other cases, I think it will be helpful in other cases.